# GOOGLE: how to prevent subpages from appearing in results

Tags: html

I have a fairly new website which allows people to create their own profiles and such. The issue is that when someone links to their profile from their website/blog, their profile shows up in google searches for my website - and to date the **one** person who has done this has a NSFW profile. Which means, when you search for my site on Google one of the top results is a NSFW page.

How do I prevent google from listing subpages in the results? Would robots.txt solve this? And if a page is *already* listed, will adding an entry in robots.txt disallowing access to profile pages in general end up removing it from the results?

Comment: Should be on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

robots.txt will solve it to some extent.  If there are direct external links, then I have found that google still indexes them.

Go to http://webmaster.google.com, get your website claimed, and then use their URL removal tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see http://www.robotstxt.org/. Just list things like "Disallow: /profile/" etc and google will stop indexing them and after a time, remove them.